# SQL Grouping of Salaries

Tags: sql, output

I have a question to ask and I am supposed to create a query which shows:

```
  MIN(lastname)   MAX(firstname)   SUM(salary)    AVG(salary)
---------------------------------------------------------------
  DAVIES            TRINA           17500           3500
```

This was the query/queries I created:

```
 SQL> SELECT MIN(LASTNAME), MAX(FIRSTNAME), SUM(SALARY), AVG(SALARY)
 2  FROM EMPLOYEES
 3  GROUP BY JOB_ID;

 SQL> SELECT MIN(LASTNAME), MAX(FIRSTNAME), SUM(SALARY), AVG(SALARY)
 2  FROM EMPLOYEES
 3  GROUP BY JOB_ID, MANAGER_ID;
```

But I get multiple rows shown to me and in the part where DAVIES TRINA was shown the SUM and AVG salary is different and I am unsure how they were grouped.

```
  MIN(LASTNAME) MAX(FIRSTNAME) SUM(SALARY) AVG(SALARY)
     ---------- ---------- ----------- -----------
      ERNST      DIANA            10200        5100
      HIGGINS    SHELLEY          12000       12000
      GIETZ      WILLIAM           8300        8300
      MOURGOS    KEVIN             5800        5800
      WHALEN     JENNIFER          4400        4400
      DE HAAN    NENA             34000       17000
      ZLOTKEY    ELENI            10500       10500
      HARTSTEIN  MICHAEL          13000       13000
      KING       STEVEN           24000       24000
      ABEL       KIMBERLEY        26600  8866.66667
      FAY        PAT               6000        6000
      **DAVIES     TRINA            11700        2925**
```

What am I doing wrong?
MORE INFO BELOW:

EMPLOYEE_ID FIRSTNAME  LASTNAME   JOB_ID         SALARY MANAGER_ID DEPARTMENT_ID

---

```
    100 STEVEN     KING       AD_PRES         24000                       90
    101 NENA       KOCHAR     AD_VP           17000        100            90
    102 LEX        DE HAAN    AD_VP           17000        100            90
    103 ALEXANDER  HUNOLD     IT_PROG                      101            60
    104 BRUCE      ERNST      IT_PROG          6000        102            60
    107 DIANA      LORENTZ    IT_PROG          4200        103            60
    124 KEVIN      MOURGOS    ST_MAN           5800        100            50
    141 TRINA      RAJS       ST_CLERK         3500        124            50
    142 CURTIS     DAVIES     ST_CLERK         3100        124            50
    143 RANDALL    MATOS      ST_CLERK         2600        124            50
    144 PETER      VARGAS     ST_CLERK         2500        124            50
```

EMPLOYEE_ID FIRSTNAME  LASTNAME   JOB_ID         SALARY MANAGER_ID DEPARTMENT_ID

---

```
    149 ELENI      ZLOTKEY    SA_MAN          10500        100            80
    174 ELLEN      ABEL       SA_REP          11000        149            50
    176 JONATHAN   TAYLOR     SA_REP           8600        149            80
    178 KIMBERLEY  GRANT      SA_REP           7000        149
    200 JENNIFER   WHALEN     AD_ASST          4400        101            10
    201 MICHAEL    HARTSTEIN  MK_MAN          13000        100            20
    202 PAT        FAY        MK_REP           6000        201            20
    205 SHELLEY    HIGGINS    AC_MGR          12000        101           110
    206 WILLIAM    GIETZ      AC_ACCOUNT       8300        205           110
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you provide the proper data that is, the data before running the query/queries and also tell why it should be 17500(sum) and 3500(avg) then you have more chances to get answers.

In the 1st query you are grouping based on JOB_ID. That means for all similar JOB_IDs (in case of SUM(SALARY)) it will select the the values of SALARY column and SUM the values for each different JOB_ID.

Example:

```
JOB_ID SALARY
   1    200
   2    300
   1    150
   2    100
   3    270
```

If you run the following query:

```
Select JOB_ID,SUM(SALARY) FROM Table GROUP BY JOB_ID
```

Output:

```
JOB_ID SALARY
  1     350
  2     400
  3     270
```

Comment: hi i added the actual table into my question.. I was not sure how they're grouping the outcome..

Comment: hope you got the desired answer.